# update нескольких ячеек в строке таблицы WebSql

Tags: javascript, sql, объекты

Подскажите, будет ли работать такой код? И если нет, то как правильно задать условия для обновления нескольких ячеек в одной строке?

```
db.init.updateOrder = function (objIn) {

        var database = db.init.db;

        database.transaction(function (tx) {

            tx.executeSql("UPDATE SomeBase SET " +
                "get_timeEnd=? AND " +
                "det_name=? AND " +
                "get_contact=? AND " +
                "get_model=? AND " +
                "get_VIN=? AND " +
                "get_yearOfMake=? AND " +
                "get_grz=? AND " +
                "get_run=? AND " +
                "get_work=? AND " +
                "get_priceWork=? AND " +
                "get_totalPriceWork=? AND " +
                "get_sparePart=? AND " +
                "get_priceSparePart=? AND " +
                "get_totalPriceSparePart=? AND " +
                "get_executor=? AND " +
                "get_notes=? AND " +
                "get_totalPrice=? " +
                "WHERE get_date=? " +
                "AND get_numberOrder=?", [
                objIn.timeEnd,
                objIn.name,
                objIn.contact,
                objIn.model,
                objIn.VIN,
                objIn.yearOfMake,
                objIn.grz,
                objIn.runing,
                objIn.work,
                objIn.priceWork,
                objIn.totalPriceWork,
                objIn.sparePart,
                objIn.priceSparePart,
                objIn.totalPriceSparePart,
                objIn.executor,
                objIn.notes,
                objIn.totalPrice,
                objIn.date,
                objIn.numberOrder]);

        });

    };
```

Comment: А вы пробуйте, зачем спрашивать. С виду запрос рабочий

Comment: @Mike уже попробовал и не работает, не пойму в чем проблема. Видимо все же не правильно.

Comment: Так вы ему функцию обработки ошибок передайте и выведите в консоль что именно ему не нравится, отгадывание ошибок по кофейной гуще нынче не в моде

Comment: @Mile, не поможете с обработчиком ошибки? не пойму как ее отловить.

Comment: после массива аргументов идут функция результата и функция ошибки, вот вторую определите и в ней сделайте console.log например

Comment: @Mike, и что в консоль вывести? я вот этот момент понять не могу.

Comment: Второй параметр этой функции, который обычно error называют. Как я понимаю там должна быть структура с информацией об ошибке

Comment: @Mike, да, разобрался уже как отловить ошибку. Спасибо за подсказки! Если в кратце, то вместо AND после SET нужны занятые, ну и у меня опечатка была в названии одного столбца.